# How create the following type as a cross reference in MS-WORD 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, cross-reference, citations

I have written a research paper.The References Section has the references in the following manner:

[1] Author, Rest Details

The cross-reference section in word is not showing the above type in Numbered Type.How can I add the above type as a reference to a number in square brackets in body of my paper?

For eg:

.....line[3] //This is a line withing the body of my paper using reference 3.

&

[3] Author, Rest Details //This is the reference.

Only numbers are to be referred within the square brackets.

Comment: What do you mean by "Numbered Type"?

Comment: Did you use the Insert Citation to create your list, and then generate a Bibliography at the end?  Once sources are created, , you can insert the square bracketed references via the Insert Citation button.  Alternatively, create an outline numbered style with numbering formatted as [1], and apply to your reference list.  Outline numbered paragraphs will appear in the "Numbered item" list in the cross-reference dialog.

Answer (score 0):

(Except when I write "Rodolfo:" the text comes from https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008180_Numbering_with_Sequence_Fields.html, with minor edits.)

Do the following to create the numbers before each reference:

1. Position the insertion point where you want the sequential number to appear. For instance, this would be in the caption for the table or figure.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to insert field curly brackets. Make sure the insertion point stays between the brackets.
3. Type **"seq "** followed by the name of the element. This name is up to you, but should be the same for each item in this sequence. For instance, you could type "**seq references**" (without the quote marks).
4. Press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the field information. Word replaces the field with the next number in the sequence you have specified.
5. Type an opening square bracket before and a closing square bracket after the number generated by the SEQ field.
6. Select everything you created in steps 1 through 5.
7. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. Word displays the Create New Building Block dialog box.

   [image: Create New Building Block dialog box]
8. In the Name field enter a name by which you want this highlighted text known. This should be something short and meaningful, such as NumList or even NL (Rodolfo: or **rn**, which stands for **reference number** and will be quick to type).
9. Click on the OK button. The dialog box closes.
10. Now whenever you want to insert the number, type the name you defined in step 8, and then press the <kbd>F3</kbd> key. The field is entered in the document. Note that the number always shows up as 1, but it is updated when you print, or when you select the entire list and press <kbd>F9</kbd>.
11. Rodolfo: To update all fields, select the whole document with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (A for All). Or just select the portion including the fields. Then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the field information.

**Cross References to the created numbers (by Rodolfo Oviedo)**

A. Create a **Marker**

1. Select the number you want to cross reference
2. Ribbon – Insert – Links – Bookmarks
3. Choose a meaningful name (in the form of AuthorYear)
4. Add

B. **Cross reference** to the marker

1. Place the cursor where you want to insert the cross reference to the number
2. Ribbon – References – Captions – Cross-reference – Reference type: Bookmark
3. Choose the name chosen while creating the marker
4. Insert